# "Dispute" Credit Report by pointing out debt that they don't show?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-report

I have looked all over and it seems as though whenever anyone suggests disputing inaccurate information on your credit report, they are always referring to removing or changing existing records.

However, I find myself in a situation where I have a mortgage (over a year now) that is visible with one credit reporting agency, but the other two don't have it. It appears that besides this difference, the information on the 3 is identical. Here's the issue: the agency that can see my mortgage has my score 10-20 points higher than the other two.

Does the 'dispute' mechanism cover situations where I would like to point out debt that the agency is unaware of? Is there any other way to get this information to the other two agencies?

Comment: Have you asked your mortgage company who they report to?  Perhaps they don't report to all three.

Comment: @MrChrister I guess that is part of my question. Do I have any ability to 'force' (for lack of a better word) a company to report to a reporting agency that they normally wouldn't? Do I have the ability to go directly to the reporting agency with the info myself?

Comment: Nope.  You can't force them to report, and you can't report yourself.  (Imagine if we could report ourselves to the credit bureaus!)  The good news is that 10-20 points isn't such a big deal in the scheme of things.

Comment: Yeah, they never promised to report everything. So they cannot be wrong in not reporting something.